Why is $2A_0(X) = 0$ for a cubic threefold $X$ containing a line, over an arbitrary field $k$.
I can't quite follow Proposition 2.1 of "UNIVERSAL UNRAMIFIED COHOMOLOGY OF CUBIC FOURFOLDS CONTAINING A PLANE".
It suffices to show for points $p,q$ on $X$ that $2(p-q) \sim 0$. If $p,q$ lie on a line, we are done. In general, we can reduce to the case where $p$ lies on the line $L$. Let $P$ be the $2$-plane spanned by $L$ and $q$. Then $P = L \cup C$ for some conic $C$ containing a point $q$. Thus $C$ is rational, unless it is the union of two lines $L_1 \cup L_2$ over some finite extension of $k$.
In any case $p \sim p'$ for some point $p'$ which lies on $C \cap L$. Then $p' \sim q$ in the case that $C$ is geometrically irreducible. So the only issue is if $C$ is a union of two lines? Then:

How does one conclude in this case that $2(p' - q) \sim 0$
Generically in the space of $2$-planes through $L$, the situation is that $C$ is geometrically irreducible, so can we not always reduce to this case?

Further, this case is only an issue when the two lines are non-split. Thus the Galois action of the degree two extension L/k which splits the lines acts by swapping the lines. Therefore it is only an issue when $q = L_1 \cap L_2$. Let $\pi:Bl_L(X) \to \mathbb{P}^2$ be the usual conic bundle with discriminant $\Delta$. Then does the section $\Delta \to X$ satisfy that $A_0(\Delta) \to A_0(X)$ is surjective?
